# Xamarin Forms: How to parse a JSON response without a stable key?

Tags: json, xamarin.forms, expander

I am using `Newtonsoft.Json` to parse my response. But for the below response I don't know how to create a model class and how to show it on an expander.

**My Response:**

```
{
"calendarEvents": {
        "2021-05-03T05:00:00.000+0000": [
            {
                "title": "Event 2",
                "description": "Event 2"
            }
        ],
        "2021-05-04T05:00:00.000+0000": [
            {
                "title": "Event 3",
                "description": "Event 3"
            }
        ],
        "2021-05-05T05:00:00.000+0000": [
            {
                "title": "Event 3",
                "description": "Event 3"
            },
            {
                "title": "Event 4",
                "description": "Event 4"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**I tried something like below:**

```
public class MyEvents
{
    public List<calendarEvents> calendarEvents { get; set; }
}

public class calendarEvents
{
    //What will be here? it is also a list and it has no stable key
}

public class Dummy//(Top class name here)
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

Instead of `2021-05-03T05:00:00.000+0000` this what I can add to the model class? The response is a list of items inside another list. Plan to use an expander to show this on UI, so any extra implementation need for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked with the back end team and they changed the JSON response like below:

```
{
    "calendarEvents": [
        {
            "day": "20210503",
            "list": [
                {
                    "title": "Event 3",
                    "description": "Event 3"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "day": "20210504",
            "list": [
                {
                    "title": "Event 3",
                    "description": "Event 3"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Event 4",
                    "description": "Event 4"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "day": "20210505",
            "list": [
                {
                    "title": "Event 3",
                    "description": "Event 3"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Event 4",
                    "description": "Event 4"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Event 5",
                    "description": "Event 5"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Corressponding Model Class:

```
public class List
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class CalendarEvent
{
    public string day { get; set; }
    public List<List> list { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<CalendarEvent> calendarEvents { get; set; }
}
```

Now I am able to parse the data and show it on an expander.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
public class calendarEvents
{
    public Dictionary<string, List<Dummy>> item {get; set;}
}

public class Dummy//(Top class name here)
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

This is how your calendarEvents should look. You can change string to DateTime.

Your model of this example JSON is bad and it should look like this:

```
public class MyEvents
{
    [JsonProperty("calendarEvents")]
    public Dictionary<string, List<CalendarEvent>> calendarEvents{ get; set; }
}

public class CalendarEvent
{
    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Using this code how can I Bind the data like DateTime(20210505T0500000000000) and title(Event 3) to the expander?

Comment: `foreach(var item in calendarEvents){
  foreach(var item2 in item.value)
   expander.ADD(item.key, item2.Title);}`